# Can't activate virtualenv

Tags: django, windows, command-prompt

So I've been using Django 1.7 for a while now and I have it set up in a virtualenv on Windows Vista. I would always activate the virtualenv from the command prompt with

```
./Scripts/activate
```

But for some reason, when I tried was using it again for the first time in several months, when I would try to activate it, I got

```
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I tried running the command

```
path/to/venv/Scripts/activate
```

(venv is the name of my virtualenv) And it would hang for about seven minutes then do nothing.

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: on WIndows all paths use backslash so probably you need to use `.\Scripts\activate`

Comment: @miki725 I tried it, and it worked! Strange because I didn't need to that before. Thanks!

Comment: great. in case others find the question, I posted the answer as well

Answer (score 1):

On Windows all paths use backslash so probably you need to use `.\Scripts\activate`